# MySQL : Select number of unique days between two dates

Tags: mysql

I have a table that shows events that took place during several days in a spatial grid and I want to select the number of unique days for each cell of the grid in order to obtain the number of days where an event happend, here my table structure :

```
+-----+------------+------------+---------+---------+
| id  | start_date |  end_date  | id_cell |  event  |
+-----+------------+------------+---------+---------+
|   1 | 2017-03-01 | 2017-03-04 |     250 | envent1 |
|   2 | 2017-03-01 | 2017-03-04 |     251 | envent1 |
|   3 | 2017-03-01 | 2017-03-04 |     307 | envent1 |
|   4 | 2017-03-01 | 2017-03-04 |     308 | envent1 |
|   5 | 2017-03-01 | 2017-03-09 |     250 | event2  |
|   9 | 2017-02-24 | 2017-03-03 |     250 | event3  |
|  13 | 2017-02-24 | 2017-03-24 |     250 | event4  |
|  17 | 2017-02-24 | 2017-03-02 |     250 | event5  |
|  21 | 2017-01-04 | 2017-01-25 |     250 | event6  |
|  25 | 2017-03-26 | 2017-03-28 |     250 | event2  |
+-----+------------+------------+---------+---------+
```

For example, the expected result for the cell with 250 as id is 51 days :

```
2017-01-04 -> 2017-01-25 = 21 days
2017-02-24 -> 2017-03-24 = 28 days
2017-03-26 -> 2017-03-28 = 2 days
```

The other dates are all included between 2017-02-24 and 2017-03-24 so they don't have to be counted so 21 + 28 + 2 = 51 days.

I tried to use DATEDIFF() like this :

```
select datediff(max(end_date) , min(start_date) ) from cell_date where id_cell = 250
```

The result is 83 because it counts the number of days between 2017-01-25 and 2017-03-01, the days where no event happened.

I tried some requests with DATEDIFF but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Someone can help me please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are unique days? can you show us the expected result for the query?

Comment: 1. Pls provide expected output on the above data. It tell us far more than your attempt to describe what you would like to achieve. 2. Pls also provide what you have tried and what was its outcome based on the sample data.

Comment: Sorry guys, it was difficult for me to explain that, I edited my post with some explanations, hope you will understand. Thanks for your interrest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by grouping by cell_id and calculating the sum of the individual differences:

```
Select cell_id,[other columns],Sum(datediff(days,start_date,end_date)) as Days
From my_table
group by cell_id,[other columns]
```

**Edit:**

For your need I think you should use an intermediate table to store individual days(sure it's not the best way to do it), join them with your events and then select the distinct days in your result. Here is the code to achieve it

```
/*Your example Talbe*/

DECLARE @T  
TABLE(ID INT,startDate DATE,EndDate DATE,id_cell INT,evnt NVARCHAR(20) )

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
(1,'2017-03-01','2017-03-04',250,'event1'),
(2,'2017-03-01','2017-03-04',251,'event1'),
(3,'2017-03-01','2017-03-04',307,'event1'),
(4,'2017-03-01','2017-03-04',308,'event1'),
(5,'2017-03-01','2017-03-09',250,'event2'),
(9,'2017-02-24','2017-03-03',250,'event3'),
(13,'2017-02-24','2017-03-24',250,'event4'),
(17,'2017-02-24','2017-03-02',250,'event5'),
(21,'2017-01-04','2017-01-25',250,'event6'),
(25,'2017-03-26','2017-03-28',250,'event2')

/*Table to store days: ideally get the start and end dates from your table */
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATE='2017-01-04'
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATE='2017-03-28'
DECLARE @DAYS  
TABLE(oneday DATE)

WHILE @StartDate <= @endDate
      BEGIN
             INSERT INTO @days
             (
                   oneday
             )
             SELECT
                   @StartDate

             SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, @StartDate)
      END


/*The request */

SELECT  id_cell,COUNT(DISTINCT oneday) NUMBER_OF_DAYS
FROM @T t
JOIN @DAYS d ON d.oneday>=t.startDate AND d.oneday<t.EndDate
WHERE id_cell=250 
GROUP BY id_cell
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but your request still count the days where there is already an event. For my example, there are three events between the event that took place between 2017-02-24 -> 2017-03-24, I don't want to count these days. Any idea to achieve that ?

Comment: Please see the code i provided in the edit.Sorry I forgot to note that it's a tsql (sqlServer) code so you have to change what's to be changed.

Comment: Well, it worked for my current table but, do you know if I add some data it will always work ?

Comment: According to this logic yes it will.but it does not prevent you from doing additional tests :p

Comment: Plus, you don't have to "physically" create a table since you can store it in a table variable in your request as it's done in the code.

Comment: After some tests I can say that it works perfectly, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You could use max and min date and datediff for obtain the diff in  days between the date eg: for event

```
select event, datediff(max(end_date) , min(star_date) ) 
from my_table 
group by event
```

or yuo can sum  by cell_id  for the total for cell_id

```
select cell_id, sum(datediff(end_date , star_date) )as  days
from my_table 
group by cell_id
```

or 
Looking to your sample seems you need  max  end_date for some event occurring starting from the same date

```
  select id_cell, sum(datediff(max_end_date, start_date)) as days 
      from ( 
      select id_cell, start_date, max(end_date) as max_end_date
      from cell_date 
      group by id_cell, start_date ) t
  group by id_cell
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried your request but I want to know the number of days for each cell, not event. If I 'group by id_cell', it appear to not be the attended result.

Comment: i have just update the asnwer ..  hope is useful  ... let me know

Comment: I still obtain 83, I don't know how to pass by the days where there is no event...

Comment: I have update the answer  using th diffdate for each row

Comment: Like I said for iMad, it still count the days where there is already an event, is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: @PaulLemesnager   answer  updated  with another suggestion

Comment: Thanks again but know I obtain 59 instead of 51, @iMad 's last response seems correct but it imply to create a table each time there is a new event. Do you have any other idea ?

Comment: No i have no idea .. seems that you have overlapping event period that you must  manage procedurally .